# Print exactly as it is without escaping any characters

Tags: python

I want to print `{alias fmtime='find . -type f -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort'}` exactly. I don't want to escape any characters. Is there a function that prints exactly anything we give it without having to escape any special characters?

Comment: You can use `raw string` `r`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your string in triple quotes (either `'''` or `"""`) and prefix the quotes with `r` (for "raw string").

```
s =    r"""{alias fmtime='find . -type f -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort'}"""
print(s) # {alias fmtime='find . -type f -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort'}
```

That way you won't have to escape `\`, `'`, or `"`.

**Limitation**:

> [...] a raw literal cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the literal, not as a line continuation.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I am looking for.